# How can the Lebesgue-Measure be an ergodic measure on [0, 1]?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, chaos-theory

In my class on ergodic theory there was a theorem, that all ergodic $F$-invariant measures $\mu$ for a Borel-function $F: X \rightarrow X$ are extreme points of the set $M_F(X) =$ {all $F$-invariant probability-Borel-measures $\mu$ on X}. Vice versa, all $\mu \in ex(M_F(X))$ are ergodic measures. Finally, the extreme points of probability-Borel-measures on X are all Dirac measures $\delta_x, x\in X$.  (The extreme points of $M_F(X)$ should only be Dirac-measures as well, right?)

My question is, how can it be that e.g. the Lebesgue-Measure is ergodic for $T_2: [0, 1]\rightarrow [0, 1]$, where $T_2$ is the tent map defined by
\begin{equation}
T_2(x) = 
\left\{
    \begin{array}{lr}
        2x, & \text{if }  x \in [0, 1/2]\\
        2-2x, & \text{if } x\in [1/2, 1]
    \end{array}
\right\},
\end{equation}
since the Lebesgue measure is not a Dirac-Measure, but a $T_2$-invariant probability-Borel-measure on $[0,1]$.
I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but maybe someone can help me point it out.

Comment: I don't see why the extreme points of $M_F(X)$ have to be Dirac measures

Comment: I think it was answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313286/extreme-points-of-the-set-of-positive-regular-borel-measures-on-a-compact-hausdo

Comment: No, that link gives the extreme points for the set of all probability measure, not the invariant ones

Comment: Thanks! Is the conlusion $X \subset Y \Rightarrow ex(X) \subset ex(Y)$ wrong? That would explain it.

Comment: @Gecko1111 That is correct. Ergodicity is very dependent on the dynamic that you consider. The set $M(X)$ is the set of all identity-invariant probability measures, its extreme points is the set of all identity-ergodic measures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The extreme points of a subset are not necessarily extreme when considered in the superset.

The extreme points of a unit square are the corners: you can take a triangle as a subset, embedded small enough that it doesn’t touch any sides. The extreme points of this subset are the corners of the triangle, which are no longer extreme when considered in the larger square.

Comment: Thanks! So the Lebesgue measure can be (is) an extreme point of $M_F(X)$, even though it is no extreme point of $M(X)$